# Cannot display state when no jobs are available

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working on a job search app. My goal is to inform the user when there are no jobs available according to his search query. I know that the server sends status 204 when there are no jobs available. My job is to display an appropriate message when I receive status 204, but I am unable to do this.

I've tried multiple ways in my fetchJobs() function to handle the 204 status. However, none of them works - I still get an error in the RenderJobs function from JobsComponent.js.

My ActionCreator.js is this:

```
export const fetchJobs = (address, job) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(jobsLoading());
    var addressObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(address));
    var obj = {"origin": [addressObj.lng, addressObj.lat], "job_details": [job]};
    const apiUrl = baseUrl + 'api/jobs/available_jobs';
    return fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
    .then(response => {
    if (response.ok && response.status == 200) {
      return response;
    }
    else if (response.ok && response.status == 204) {
       dispatch(noJobsAvailable());
       return;
    }
    else {
      var error = new Error('Error is: ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
      error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jobs => dispatch(addJobs(jobs)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(jobsFailed(error.message)));
};

export const noJobsAvailable = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.NO_JOBS_AVAILABLE
});
```

This is my reducer:

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    jobs: [],
    isLoading: true,
    noJobs: false,
    errMess: null
  };

export const jobs = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.GET_JOBS:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, noJobs:false, errMess: null, jobs: action.payload};

        case ActionTypes.JOBS_LOADING:
            return {...state, isLoading: true, noJobs:false, errMess: null, jobs: []}

        case ActionTypes.NO_JOBS_AVAILABLE:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, noJobs: true, errMess: null, jobs: []}

        case ActionTypes.JOBS_FAILED:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, noJobs:false, errMess: action.payload};

        default:
          return state;
      }
};
```

And this is my RenderJobs function from JobsComponent.js:

```
function RenderJobs(props) {
    var json = JSON.parse(props.jobsData);
    //create a sorted array based on 'json', called sort_array
    const renderJobItem = ({item}) => {
        //process the API response for displaying it
        return (
        //component for displaying the API response
    }

if (props.isLoading) {
    return (
            <Loading /> //custom loading component
    );
}
else if (props.noJobs) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.errorView}>
        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>No jobs available</Text>                                           
    </View>
    )
}
else if (props.errMess) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.errorView}>
            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>An error occurred</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
else {
    return (
        <FlatList 
                data={sort_array}
                renderItem={renderJobItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                style={{marginTop: 10}}
                />
    );
}

}
```

What currently happens is this:

1. The first time my RenderJobs function from JobsComponent.js is called, the props.noJobs flag is *true* and props.errMess is *null*.
2. The second time my RenderJobs function is called, the props.noJobs flag is *false* and props.errMess - *"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.json')"*

I do not understand why step #2 happens. I am expecting the call to end at step #1.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help solve this mistery. :)

Comment: Looks like you return void when you dispatch no jobs available, but then the next `then` in the chain is expecting a response object with a json object.  I suspect this is causing an error to occur that is caught by your catch block. What isn't clear to me is whether or not `message` is defined in `dispatch(jobsFailed(error.message)))` or if  that action actually has a property called `payload` in `errMess: action.payload` for the reducer to process.  Have you tried getting `jobs` from the JSON response and dispatching `dispatch(addJobs(jobs))` in the first if branch?

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for the late reply. I eventually managed to solved it by handling the 204 code as an error in my JobsComponent. So in my ActionCreator I just throw an error and handle the 204 in my JobsComponent - I check if the error message includes 204 and, if so, show an appropriate message.